# Evolution mail zoom in editor

Tags: evolution

Setting:
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
evolution 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

I can zoom mails in evolution, when I have received them. But none of the shortcuts (ctrl + + or ctrl + mouse wheel) works, when I write e-mails. How can I zoom in the editor in evolution mail, when writing mails?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround so far is to use libreoffice and then paste the message into the composer editor but by far not my favorite solution. Unfortunately I have to stop using Thunderbird due to PGP issues.